# bash: printf: write error: Bad file descriptor

Tags: linux, bash, exec

While messing with redirecting socket input to a file in a Linux bash terminal, I typed the following:

```
$ exec 3>/dev/udp/127.0.0.1/5065
$ cat <&3
```

Distracted by something else, I let the terminal session expire.  On logging back in, every command I type, in the example below `ls`, produces the response `write error: Bad file descriptor`:

```
$ ls
ls: write error: Bad file descriptor
bash: printf: write error: Bad file descriptor
```

How do I return everything to normal without rebooting the machine (which is highly undesirable)?

Comment: You might try starting a new shell that explicitly uses the terminal for I/O: `bash < /dev/tty > /dev/tty`. Then you can see if you can find and kill the offending processes started in your previous session. It's not clear, though, why redirections from a previous session would affect your new login session.

Comment: Thanks for that, I can type commands in the new bash shell.  I've grepped through the running processes and `cat` doesn't turn up, so I guess it's not still running.  I've run `netstat -tulpn` and the port I grabbed with `exec` isn't listed, so I guess it's not in use.  When I `exit` from the new shell I'm back in `write error: Bad file descriptor` mode.  HOWEVER, I've just started closed that terminal and started another fresh one and all is now fine.  Weird; must have been a glitch somewhere...